# How to ping remote mysql using golang

Tags: mysql, linux, go

I am using `go` to ping some Linux machines.
But it is not work accurate, because it always needs almost 10 seconds to connect the remote mysql.

I use this command:

> mysql -u USER -p PASSWORD -h REMOTE_IP

So i want to know how to use linux command to know whether it open or not.

Then I will use golang 's  `exec.Command` to do that .

Here is my `ping` code:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/tatsushid/go-fastping"
    "net"
    "net/smtp"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main(){
    err := ping("192.168.2.1")
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println("WARNING!!!!!!")
    }
}
func ping(ip string) error {
    p := fastping.NewPinger()
    ra, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip", ip)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    p.AddIPAddr(ra)
    found := false
    p.OnRecv = func(addr *net.IPAddr, rtt time.Duration) {
        found = true
    }
    err = p.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if !found {
        return errors.New("response error")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to know if mysql is reachable or not. You can use following example:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    var (
        server = flag.String("mysql", "localhost:3306", "mysql server")
        user   = flag.String("user", "root", "mysql user")
        pass   = flag.String("password", "", "mysql password")
    )
    flag.Parse()

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s)/", *user, *pass, *server))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)

    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)

    } else {
        log.Println("mysqld is alive")

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but if I want to use db.ping() all day like `for {err = db.ping() iferr != nil {log.Fatalln(err)}}` . However ,It does not work when I poweroff some machine.

Comment: Replace `log.Fatalln` with `log.Println` and some delay with `time.Sleep` between pings.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to check connection to a specific host & port, you can do this as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

const (
    host = "192.168.2.1"
    port = "3306" // default MySQL port
)

func main() {

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", host+":"+port)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    fmt.Printf("Connected to %s \n", conn.RemoteAddr().String())
}
```

Comment: Technically valid but probably not appropriate, since this behavior causes MySQL to assume something is wrong with the connecting host and should cause warnings to be logged if `log_warnings` is set high enouhh.  By default, the server will start blocking you, which could be especially bad if you're testint through a load balancer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blocked-host.html

Comment: There's some vagueness in the haroldT's question and anyways, you cannot be sure about state of connection with MySQL w/o actually running at least a simple query like 'SELECT 1'. With all that in mind, and considering his phrase "...to ping some linux machines..." I assumed that his _only_ concern is port being open on particular host. You have a good point about blocked-host! Would be great to understand if connection attempt to port 3306 would be considered by MySQL as a "connection request"? (continued below)

Comment: (cont.) In my understanding, looking at the MySQL driver, to "officially  connect", in addition to a dial, it also doing: authentication, checks max_allowed_packet, checks charset + smth else. So maybe, just pinging the port is not leading to Host 'host_name' is blocked, because no "connection requests" actually happened. Thoughts?

Comment: A TCP connection attempt with nothing sent, followed by closing the connection, is sufficient to increment the counter. Confirmed with test:  using the (old) default value of 10, `for n in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15; do (true | nc x.x.x.x 3306 | strings | egrep '^5|blocked'); done` results in `Host 'xxxxxxx' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'` beginning with the 12th attempt (I'm not sure why it isn't the 10th or 11th, but this behavior is repeatable).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, great! Thank you for checking that.

Comment: @mpmlj,Thank you for your help.If I want to use `for` to do that , so what your suggestions did not work.I want to use goroutine to make sure the connection status.what should I do?